A First Course in Mathematical Analysis, Ch 2, 2.6 Exercises, Section 2.5, ex 3

let {$a_{n}$} be a sequence for which $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(a_{n} + \frac{l^2}{a_{n}})$ for $n \ge 1$,where $a_1 > 0$ and $l > 0$.
(a) Prove that {$a_n$} is decreasing for $n\ge2$, and hence that $a_{n} \to l$ as $n \to +\infty$.

Firstly, $a_{n}$ should be greater than 0.
I write down $a_{n+1} - a_{n} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{l^2}{a_{n}}-a_{n})$, and found nothing i can do. And i notice the condition $n \ge 2$, then I try $a_{n+1} - a_{n} = \frac{1}{2}(a_{n} + \frac{l^2}{a_{n}}) - \frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1} + \frac{l^2}{a_{n-1}}) = \frac{1}{2}(a_{n}-a_{n-1})+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{l^2}{a_{n}}-\frac{l^2}{a_{n-1}})$, and i have no idea what i can do next.
I just calculated for so long, and get no hint for solving the question.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you all for your help. Because I accepted the answer without solving the second part, it seems make this question incomplete. so I add the prove for the other part.

Base on the fact that the sequence is decreasing and bounded blow, it is convergent.
Suppose the limit is L. Since $a_{n} \ge l$, so $L \ge l \gt 0$. And $L = \frac{1}{2}(L + \frac{l^2}{L})$, we get $L^2 = l^2$. So $L=l$


What have you tried?

You should include your thinking, otherwise, it'll be closed soon.

Welcome to (posting at) MSE! <> Something is suspicious: Customarily "$a_1>0$" would read "$a_1>\ell$." If that's a type in the book, perhaps check with your instructor. (Exercise: Find a counterexample to the "decreasing" assertion under the hypotheses stated. :)

@white It's not clear to me why you accepted the solution. The "and hence" part doesn't immediately follow. We have a decreasing sequence (which converges) that is bounded below by $l$, doesn't mean that it has to converge to $l$.

@CalvinLin I'm so sorry I forget to emphasis that my main question is that how to prove $a_{n}$ is decreasing. And I know how to solve the other part of the question base on the decreasing sequence. Thank you very much for your help!

Then, can you add the other part to complete the problem?

Notice that $a_{n+1}\leq a_n \iff a_n^2\geq l^2$, and since $a_n\geq 0$, you have to prove that $a_n\geq l$, which follows from the AM-GM inequality, since $$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n^2+l^2}{2}\frac{1}{a_n}\geq \frac{\sqrt{a_n^2l^2}}{a_n}=l.$$

Note that you don't need induction for that. AM-GM works directly.

Oh yeah! Great observation, thanks :)

Note that the solution is incomplete. The "and hence" part doesn't immediately follow.
